# Atmosphere: reconnect after onClose (connection loss)

Tags: java, gwt, atmosphere

I have successfully implemented some push notification using Atmosphere and GWT, however on disconnecting / reconnecting my network connection Atmosphere invokes the onClose function. Unfortunately I'm not able to establish a proper reconnect. Transport is long-polling.

Calling something like Atmosphere.create().subscribe() is working but leads to multiple connections (or AtmosphereResources) and slows down the the whole application.
What is the recommended way to resubscribe to a broadcaster ?